# GCP Vertex AI Endpoint returning empty prediction array

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, kubeflow-pipelines, gcp-ai-platform-training

KFP pipeline job executes successfully, but upon hitting the endpoint, am getting an empty predictions array ([]).  I suspect the issue is in the model upload, where the model is not registered correctly somehow.  Any tips are appreciated.

Code to upload model deploy task:

```
    #Import a model programmatically
    model_upload = aiplatform.Model.upload(
        display_name = DISPLAY_NAME, 
        serving_container_image_uri = serving_container_image_uri,
        serving_container_health_route="/health_check",
        serving_container_predict_route="/predict",
        serving_container_ports=[8080],
        serving_container_environment_variables={
            "MODEL_NAME": MODEL_NAME,
        },       
    )
```

Code to get predictions:

```
response = endpoint.predict({"user_id": 150})
# response = endpoint.predict({"instances":{"user_id": 150}})
response
```

Response:

```
Prediction(predictions=[], deployed_model_id='4656867150235959296', explanations=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:**

Check your handler output is returning a correctly formatted string without extra slashes (`\`) in the response which meets the [requirements](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/custom-container-requirements#prediction).

Or use `raw predict` instead of `predict` call. ([guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/notebooks/community/prediction/custom_prediction_routines/SDK_Custom_Predict_and_Handler_SDK_Integration.ipynb))

---

**Debugging steps:**

I also had this issue where I was using the Vertex AI custom serving container approach and calling `endpoint.predict(instances=[{...}]).predictions` was only returning an empty list: `[]`.

Even though, when using `raw predict` from the [Python SDK](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.types.RawPredictRequest) or via [REST endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.endpoints/rawPredict), it returned a valid response for the `data` JSON key:

Python SDK response:

```json
"{\"predictions\": \"[{\\\"key1\\\": \\\"string1\\\", \\\"key2\\\": [\\\"string2\\\"], \\\"key3\\\": 0.0}]\"}"
```

REST API response:

```json
{"predictions": "[{\"key1\": \"string1\", \"key2\": [\"string2\"], \"key3\": 0.0}]"}
```

However, in both cases you can see that there were extra slashes (`\`) in the responses. This means that it was a **formatting issue**.

---

**Solution:**

It turned out that in the post-processing step of my handler, I had done the following:

```py
prediction_result = {
            "key1": value1,
            "key2": value2,
            "key3": value3,
        }
array = np.array([prediction_result])

return json.dumps({"predictions": array.tolist()})
```

Changing it to the following fixed the problem for me:

```py
prediction_result = {
            "key1": value1,
            "key2": value2,
            "key3": value3,
        }

return json.dumps({"predictions": [prediction_result]})
```

And then calling `endpoint.predict(instances=[{...}]).predictions` returned the following list for me:

```py
[{'key1': 'string1',
  'key2': ['string2'],
  'key3': 0.0}]
```

After the fix, the responses from `raw predict` no longer contained the extra slashes (`\`).

Answer (score 0):

Had the similar issue when `postprocess` returned dictionary with `str` value

```
def postprocess(self, prediction_results: str) -> Dict:
   ...
   return {"predictions": prediction_results}
```

Change `return {"predictions": prediction_results}` to `return {"predictions": [prediction_results]}` to start receive non-empty predictions